# Typescript type preventing comparison with other primitive types

Tags: typescript, typescript-eslint

**Prerequisites:** I have a variable, that I always just pass through and never manipulate or compare inside my app. (It comes from the server in one API property and is returned to the server unaltered in a different API property.)

**My question:** Is there a typescript type that prevents that this variable may ever be accidentally compared to another variable of a different type?

**Example:**

```js
type MyUnknownPassthroughServerType = string;

function getSomethingFromTheServer(): MyUnknownPassthroughServerType {
  return <MyUnknownPassthroughServerType>'test';
}

function writeSomethingToTheServer(payload: MyUnknownPassthroughServerType): void {}

const serverVar = getSomethingFromTheServer();

if (serverVar === 'test') { // <- I want a compilation error on this
  // Do something
}

if (serverVar === 1) { // <- I want a compilation error on this
  // Do something
}

writeSomethingToTheServer(serverVar); // <- That should be fine
writeSomethingToTheServer('test') // <- I want a compilation error on this
```

**Ugly solution:**
Declaring it as some type that will never have any overlap with another type would work of course (e.g. `type MyUnknownPassthroughServerType = {neverUsed: boolean};`). But isn't there a better way to do this?

If that is not possible in typescript alone, I could also resort to an eslint solution, if you know of any...?

Comment: FWIW, your "ugly solution" isn't that ugly IMHO, except I'd use `unique symbol`. But it can still be compared to `object`. :-( https://tsplay.dev/mp8BBm

Comment: Hi - thanks for your quick response! Here's the sample that you requested: https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-1qu5ys?file=index.ts (<- I want compilation errors on all the lines that I annotated with the respective comment.)
I didn't know about `unique symbol`, but as far as I can see, it cannot be used in type definitions, or can it?

Comment: *"I didn't know about unique symbol, but as far as I can see, it cannot be used in type definitions, or can it?"* Sure, see [my link above](https://tsplay.dev/mp8BBm), which uses it in a type definition.

Comment: I'll be really keen to see if there's a better answer than variations on your "ugly" one. Interesting question!

Comment: _Thanks Please put the full (minimal) example code in the question, not just linked._

Done.  (I just didn't want to have that many lines in the question, that's why I tried to use my words instead of code.)

_Sure, see my link above, which uses it in a type definition._
Yes, but I'd need it in a definition such as `type MyUnknownPassthroughTyp = unique symbol;`. Otherwise you have the  `__never_used__` which I consider ugly - as I said. But if there's no other way around it, I'll go for that. `unique symbol` makes it a bit better, thanks!

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Even if object can still be compared, I would urge you to write an answer with your approach. I didn't know about this and it's very useful.

Comment: @lentschi check [this](https://tsplay.dev/wXzB9m). Also it is impossible to forbid comparisons for some particular string literal from TS perspective. You can write a plugin to eslint

Comment: @lentschi - Sorry, I meant "I'd use `unique symbol` rather than `boolean`," as shown in the linked example. That way, it can never be matched, whereas *in theory* you could have an object with `neverused: true` in it.

Comment: @Etheryte - Thanks! Done. :-) I don't normally like to post an answer which really just tweaks something in the question, but if it was useful... (I marked it Community Wiki because I didn't want to get rep from it.)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's possible to define a type that will make all comparisons with it (except itself) fail. Your "ugly" solution achieves most of what you want to do and is probably your best bet, though you might use [`unique symbol`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/symbols.html#unique-symbol) rather than `boolean` (because I can create a `{neverused: true}` object). Sadly, though, comparisons with `object` are allowed, but it at least disallows comparisons with *specific types* of objects:

```typescript
type MyUnknownPassthroughServerType = { readonly __never_used__: unique symbol };

function getSomethingFromTheServer(): MyUnknownPassthroughServerType {
    return "test" as any as MyUnknownPassthroughServerType;
}

function writeSomethingToTheServer(payload: MyUnknownPassthroughServerType): void {}

const serverVar = getSomethingFromTheServer();

writeSomethingToTheServer(serverVar); // <- Works as desired
writeSomethingToTheServer("test"); // <- Compilation error as desired

// Strings are not allowed
serverVar === "test"; // <- Compilation error as desired

// Numbers are not allowed
serverVar === 1; // <- Compilation error as desired

// Booleans are not allowed
serverVar === true; // <- Compilation error as desired

// `object` is allowed :-(
declare const someObject: object;
serverVar === someObject; // <- Sadly, no error here

// But not more specific objects
declare const someObject2: { a: number };
serverVar === someObject2; // <- Compilation error as desired
declare const someRecord: Record<string, number>;
serverVar === someRecord; // <- Compilation error as desired

// `null` and undefined are allowed
serverVar === null;
serverVar === undefined;
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiCqA7A1og9gd0QBQIYGd9gALAJzQFcBzYgZQlIDcGAVcaAXigG8pSJcAEzSIANiCgB9SYgjNSkivgiDpALigVEASwCOFaPhABbAEZpRUAL4BuAFB2AZloDGwbSKhUIwWmmM+xNqIVABi5MYsxBD0TAwAFACUGnBIqJg4BERklDSx8myQPHZQpXw+FKSIUABEwBBENVAEzYgSLako6Fh4hCTk1HQMBez2Vg7OiG4e1Rik2vV+ASTBVCxoUTHDCWC4IKJoQikIXRm92QN526SFEMlQjGjagjzjdi4iRFDKcaQAarhSFAuN5fP5Aqtwv5NvkEol7HY5gsYuCViF1jDrvEfvIAaR4VAAPSEqAAHgAtFAAOpoUjIfDNBmCBrafiCRHzRaooLojbRWGkeJ1BrAGoE4lkykAYX8YG0olw7k8DHIQJazPwrJUDgltGA8xCDMB0HQwGaogOGG1OIYeOBHC4wsaNiJJIpUBlxjlCqV1RVtMZUA1WvZdglADkKGYGEb+FBTebLdbrnaHVwAIwuiXuz3exUzKD+tVMllsnUkgBCaAsAkQsZNaDNuAtmGTv1TDqg+oMWbd0tl8vzytIqsDwbLYZJAAM0KYAFYQNxTqDaI0tq0vNTk+J2ZkuBVxj51s34cEAeXni+AGlnC7c9ht-0B9q4p4CF7vwF7kqgtCE4gAGnjNBCxHANon4csoArCgzQTYxaUMSAXG0RxtBcKBbyvfBd0XA9oCPL43wgD8rwAJg0XhcA0RAo1MBhrAfFNnzTb5z0vNwyO-HMBx9AsizHUttT3fCoEIk9wQAJUXWlBA0aSPlIQRSSIA0qCA2jo1IAA+Jj2xYztiIU2TuP7L1B19UDR3VITQwlKdaItZdcEQF4tGZNDZBeY1E1bdlHw7LhHNEPTcQMrh3IgTyVBsIA)

Another trick is `string & { _tag: 'MyUnknownPassthroughServerType' }` as [captain yossarian from Ukraine pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75083303/typescript-type-preventing-comparison-with-other-primitive-types?noredirect=1#comment132500611_75083303), but it allows comparisons with strings.

Comment: Thanks again! The fact that it's comparable to generic objects doesn't hurt me at all as I try to avoid such loose declarations. Of course I do use `unknown` sometimes, but it is obvious that I can't prevent accidental comparison to _that_ as it is the nature of the unknown :-)